# Draggable window in a EditorWindow extended class

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a complex GUI element consistent of buttons, text fields etc. I'd like to be able to move this group, but I can't find a way how.

I tried making a BeginArea, placing all the elements in it and moving the area. For that used a `GUI.RepeatButton` to check when the mouse button is pressed. It worked, but the update fires only twice and then stops. So I couldn't use this method for smooth dragging.

I've also tried `Window` to use it with `GUI.DragWindow()`, but it seems it doesn't work within classes that extend `EditorWindow`.

Is there a way to make a draggable group for a custom EditorWindow class?

Comment: Actually `GUI.DragWindow() ` should work with `EditorWindow`. Can you show us the code maybe you missed something

Comment: The code was copy-pasted from the unity official documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Window.html The result was a blank panel - no content. Unity ver 4.53

Comment: It's for normal GUI, logic is the same but some parts are missing for EditorWindow.For example, did you add `BeginWindows();` and `EndWindows();` inside `OnGUI` method ?

Comment: Oh, I did not, thank you for pointing that out. I guess this question is answered now, thanks!